# Adding key to IPad keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, keyboard, jailbreak

i am currently working on an iPad application, my client wants to add Function keys as in normal keyboard on Top of keypad which i have done. 
Problem is he wants a "Fn" key in the iPad system keyboard which ll show the Function keys when clicked.

Is it possible without jail break ? as he sent me some pics where it is done.. but i have googled a lot, but i could n't find any Apple's document which says 'application will be rejected if it interfers with system keyboard or something like that..

Any pointers on How to do add Fn key in keyboard or something which i can show to convince him , s really appreciated..

EDIT : solution to add but only if you want to learn how you can do it.. **BUT ITS NOT WHAT YOU SHOULD DO FOR  A REAL APP**

[Follow this link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html)  to find the KEYBOARD layer of the iPad NOTE: you need to check for `UIPeripheralHostView` on iPad , UIKeyboard works for iPhone.

After that final if condition where you find the UIPeripheralHostView 
add one more loop for its subViews and check condition for `UIKeyboardAutomatic`

After that is done.. you need do a recursive Call like iOS do for doing a `HitTest`
CGPoint can be anything depending on where you want to add key, in my case its like 
CGPoint(50,290) for the bottom right key.

so keep looping in subviews while converting your CGPoint into local coordinate system of the parent View(you can start with *nil* parent view after UIKeyboardAutomatic is found.

Final return condition is if your view is of class `UIKBKeyView` and it can respond to your hitTest point.  you got your key view and its parent.. now add whatever you want to add ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wolfram Alpha app did something similar. When the keyboard is shown, they add their own view directly above it. They're using `-inputAccessoryView`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html for more info.

You can also completely replace the keyboard with `-inputView`.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha didn't need a jailbreak, it is on the App Store.

If you mean you want proof that you can't modify the Apple portion of the keyboard, I don't know where I'd find that, but I've never seen a single app that modified the keyboard. I just don't think an API exists.

Comment: Added links to the documentation for `-inputAccessoryView`.

Comment: i did the same. he wants me to put a Fn key in bottom near spacebar or !123 key.. i am searching for some link from apple.. to convince him..

Comment: i found a way to put 'Fn' key in the bottom inside the keyboard and shifting ?!123 key also to make space.. but i don't knw how good the idea is.. ll post the code in morning..

Comment: Yeah? I'm dying to see how. Make sure you also test it with multiple keyboards turned on (e.g. enable Emoji or Chinese keyboard).

Comment: sorry to disappoint you.. i got it working on normal alphabetic keyboard.. but its not a permanent solution..my friend suggested me how to do that..it was just to show my client that its possible.. but its not at all a good idea to do it.

Comment: How well does that work if you drag the keyboard up the screen (into split mode)?

Comment: it doesn't work in split mode of keyboard, but ll work if you just undock it.. as split causes a full keyboard layout again, but undock doesn't and we added the key when it was docked..

Comment: The keyboard can come up in split mode if the user split it before. My keyboard is usually in split mode.

Comment: you can split also working for iOS 5 as you can use keydidshownotification.. but in latest 5.0.1 or whatever updated version has come.. keyboard don't send this notification.. so it won't work. :(